# MySQL Attendance IN & OUT columns with correct times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database for attendance, it works fine as long as the person does not work over 2 dates. I want to utilize IN and OUT system for records but I do not know how to do the final step, and what I saw on the forum does not work on MySQL or I am doing something wrong there.
This is my database and queries are under.
BTW Database is built using PHPmyadmin and MySQL Workbench.

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `indexing` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp()    ) ;



INSERT INTO `entries` (`indexing`, `emp_id`, `Date`) VALUES
(61, 1, '2020-07-07 05:41:36'),
(62, 1, '2020-07-07 05:44:21'),
(63, 2, '2020-07-07 05:44:36'),
(64, 3, '2020-07-07 05:49:23'),
(65, 2, '2020-07-07 05:49:39'),
(66, 3, '2020-07-07 05:50:00'),
(67, 4, '2020-07-07 09:56:51'),
(68, 5, '2020-07-07 09:57:13'),
(69, 3, '2020-07-07 09:57:18'),
(70, 2, '2020-07-07 09:57:28'),
(71, 1, '2020-07-07 09:57:42'),
(72, 4, '2020-07-07 09:57:49'),
(73, 5, '2020-07-07 09:59:38'),
(74, 1, '2020-07-08 05:59:42'),
(75, 2, '2020-07-08 06:00:05'),
(76, 3, '2020-07-08 06:38:20'),
(77, 1, '2020-07-08 09:47:43'),
(78, 4, '2020-07-08 09:56:14'),
(79, 5, '2020-07-08 09:56:47'),
(80, 1, '2020-07-08 09:56:59'),
(81, 3, '2020-07-08 09:57:34'),
(82, 2, '2020-07-08 09:58:07'),
(83, 4, '2020-07-08 09:58:11'),
(84, 5, '2020-07-08 09:59:20'),
(85, 5, '2020-07-08 09:59:50'),
(86, 4, '2020-07-08 11:08:36'),
(87, 3, '2020-07-08 11:09:30');

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `emp_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `company` set('First','second') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'First',
  `department` set('Outbound','Inbound','UE','Returns','QC','Cleaner','Admin','IT 
   Technician','Supervisor','Manager') NOT NULL,
  `driver` set('PPT','VNA','HLOP','CB','PPT VNA HLOP','PPT HLOP','PPT CB') DEFAULT NULL
) ;


INSERT INTO `user` (`emp_id`, `Name`, `company`, `department`, `driver`) VALUES
(1, 'Micinka', 'second', 'IT Technician', ''),
(2, 'Dusbica', 'First', 'IT Technician', ''),
(3, 'Klaudocka', 'First', 'Returns', ''),
(4, 'Patrycginis', 'First', 'Cleaner', ''),
(5, 'Stuistow', 'First', 'Cleaner', '');


--
ALTER TABLE `entries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`indexing`),
  ADD KEY `emp_id` (`emp_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`);


-- Constraints for table `entries`
--
ALTER TABLE `entries`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `entries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`emp_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

This are the Queries, and last one is how I would want the table look like but with IN and OUT times correct, now are both same.

```
select entries.emp_id, entries.Date, dense_rank() over (partition by entries.emp_id order by entries.indexing) % 2 AS 'IN and OUT' from entries;
  
    drop table report_inout;
        create view report_inout as select entries.emp_id, entries.Date,
        CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY entries.emp_id ORDER BY entries.Date) % 2 = 0
             THEN 'OUT' ELSE 'IN' END AS `IN and OUT`         
    FROM entries
    ORDER BY
        entries.indexing;
 
select date_format(report_inout.Date,'%d/%M/%Y') as `Date`,user.Name, time_format(report_inout.Date,'%H:%i:%s')  as `IN`, time_format(report_inout.Date,'%H:%i:%s')  as `OUT`,
    user.company as Company,user.department as Department from report_inout
    join user on user.emp_id = report_inout.emp_id
    group by user.Name, report_inout.`In and Out`;
```

This are the results from my queries i posted.

```
emp_id;"Date";"IN and OUT"
1;"2020-07-07 05:41:36";"IN"
1;"2020-07-07 05:44:21";"OUT"
2;"2020-07-07 05:44:36";"IN"
3;"2020-07-07 05:49:23";"IN"
2;"2020-07-07 05:49:39";"OUT"
3;"2020-07-07 05:50:00";"OUT"
4;"2020-07-07 09:56:51";"IN"
5;"2020-07-07 09:57:13";"IN"
3;"2020-07-07 09:57:18";"IN"
2;"2020-07-07 09:57:28";"IN"
1;"2020-07-07 09:57:42";"IN"
4;"2020-07-07 09:57:49";"OUT"
5;"2020-07-07 09:59:38";"OUT"
1;"2020-07-08 05:59:42";"OUT"
2;"2020-07-08 06:00:05";"OUT"
3;"2020-07-08 06:38:20";"OUT"
1;"2020-07-08 09:47:43";"IN"
4;"2020-07-08 09:56:14";"IN"
5;"2020-07-08 09:56:47";"IN"
1;"2020-07-08 09:56:59";"OUT"
3;"2020-07-08 09:57:34";"IN"
2;"2020-07-08 09:58:07";"IN"
4;"2020-07-08 09:58:11";"OUT"
5;"2020-07-08 09:59:20";"OUT"
5;"2020-07-08 09:59:50";"IN"
```

and last query is this one, but it has always same time in IN and OUT

```
Date;"Name";"IN";"OUT";"Company";"Department"
08/July/2020;"Dusbica";"09:58:07";"09:58:07";"First";"IT Technician"
08/July/2020;"Dusbica";"06:00:05";"06:00:05";"First";"IT Technician"
08/July/2020;"Klaudocka";"09:57:34";"09:57:34";"First";"Returns"
08/July/2020;"Klaudocka";"11:09:30";"11:09:30";"First";"Returns"
08/July/2020;"Micinka";"09:47:43";"09:47:43";"second";"IT Technician"
08/July/2020;"Micinka";"09:56:59";"09:56:59";"second";"IT Technician"
08/July/2020;"Patrycginis";"11:08:36";"11:08:36";"First";"Cleaner"
08/July/2020;"Patrycginis";"09:58:11";"09:58:11";"First";"Cleaner"
08/July/2020;"Stuistow";"09:59:50";"09:59:50";"First";"Cleaner"
08/July/2020;"Stuistow";"09:59:20";"09:59:20";"First";"Cleaner"
```

Comment: What is your task? Find errors - IN without OUT and backward? Extract adjacent IN/OUT rows pairs? Calculate separate or total attendance time? Something else?

Comment: Your current structure does not allow to distinguish IN and OUT rows.

Comment: @Akina I am not sure if this answers your question, but I can get In and Out results  now, I just do not know how to match it in one row. If you have any other idea how i could do i would be very greatfull

Comment: Your dump is wrong. NEVER allow linebreaks in ENUM values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. 1st record for each separate `emp_id` is IN event
2. There is no lost events

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT emp_id, `Date`, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY `Date`) - 1 rn
              FROM entries )
SELECT t1.emp_id, user.name, t1.`Date` in_date, t2.`Date` out_date
FROM user
JOIN cte t1 ON user.emp_id = t1.emp_id
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
                AND t1.rn DIV 2 = t2.rn DIV 2
                AND t2.rn MOD 2
WHERE NOT t1.rn MOD 2
ORDER BY emp_id, in_date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6dd1412c89b74a11aee1ddad9d7d4fb)

---

Idea.

We enumerate all rows for each employee separately starting with zero. So first IN is 0, first OUT is 1, 2nd IN is 2 and so on.

You can see that matched IN and OUT events will give the same result after integer divide their numbers by 2. And the reminder for IN will be 0 whereas for OUT it will be 1.

This is enough for correct joining.

Second copy of CTE table is joining using LEFT join because the last IN row may have no according OUT row - this means that the employee is now present at the object. And final row will contain NULL in `out_date` column in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I cannot use it, i saw similar solution elswhere, but it showing error on `WITH` satement it says - Unrecognized statement type near WITH. I am using mySQL ~ PHP myadmin.

Comment: @nahaku You use DENSE_RANK() - i.e. your MySQL version is 8+. So this looks like phpmyadmin issue - refresh its version.

Comment: not sure what is going on, sometimes I use some query it goes all well, I change nothing and later it shows error, then i maybe close and open it again or do something else and it starts to work....

Comment: as i said I tried It again and now it works. About that privious reply, it showed error on PHPmyadmin when i pasted the statement there. but it allowed me to execute it. It was misleading, I will try this one as it is short for some time. Thank you boss.